# Sort output of find based on regex

Tags: regex, bash, sorting

I have a `find` command, which lists all the directories containing a matching substring. The directories matching the `find` command are all formatted as such:

```
a_bunch_of_stuff_20210110_101945_more_stuff/
a_bunch_of_stuff_20201225_101934_more_stuff/
a_bunch_of_stuff_20210106_101933_more_stuff/
```

As you can see, each directory name has a bunch of text following and leading a **datetime** in the form of `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS`.

I want to sort the output of the find command based on these datetime strings, from oldest to newest. I can't simply do a `| sort`, because the "a_bunch_of_stuff_" following the datetime can be anything.

Is there a way to sort based on a regex, similar to how I can do so in the `find` command? Note: performance here is not of concern.

Comment: It is easy to use `sort` with your example input; can you provide an almost real output of the `find` command? Will there be always the same paths lengths? Will there be always the same number of underscores in the directories names? Are you using GNU `find`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution (if your paths don't contain newlines):

```sh
find . -type d -name 'somefilter' |
sed -En 's|.*/.*_([[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6})_.*|\1 &|p' |
sort -k1,1 |
sed -E 's/[^ ]* //'
```

The pipeline works as follows:

1. find the matching dirpaths
2. search for the `_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_` pattern in each dir**name** and prepend it to the output; drop the dirpaths that don't match.
3. sort considering the first column only (which is `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS`)
4. remove the first column from the output

Answer (score 1):

If you can use perl and data can fit into memory :

```
find ... | perl -e 'use Sort::Key qw(keysort); map { print; } keysort { /(\d{8}_\d{6})/; $1 } (<>)'
```

You might need to tune the regex.

Comment: I had to install Sort::Key for making it work but nice solution ;-)

Comment: @Fravadona I have perl 5.32.1, so Sort::Key is already included. `perl` version is more verbose than your `sort` version, but it avoids changing input data.